# Can't add UIButton on custom UITableView without an error

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uibutton, storyboard

## What I'm trying to achieve:

Trying to achieve Google-Now-style like custom TableViewCell with couple of buttons on each card (refer to the provided screenshot [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iiyLb.jpg)).   ***Using Storyboard.***

## Problem

I was able to make the card like TableViewCells, but whenever I try to place a UIButton on the card, it will either cause a compiler error or a runtime error.

## Current setup

My current storyboard set up looks like [this](https://imgur.com/a/1npPZ).

[Here](https://imgur.com/a/1npPZ)'s my code for the TableView.

## What I've tried so far

- Drag and dropped the UIButton on top of my card view, which looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCrpq.jpg). Button get buried down somewhere under the tableview? Button does not appear like it should and once I create an outlet to the actual code, compiler error (invalid outlets cannot be connected to repeating content).
- Placed the UIButton on top of the Content View. This outputs in same result as above.
- Placed the UIButton on top of the View. Now this actually shows the button on the storyboard, however it causes a runtime error and crashes while it tries to display this ViewController. 
  [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SEwEL.jpg) is how it's set up on the Storyboard.

Now, what am I doing wrong here? I've looked at several tutorials on how to place a UIButton on a TableViewCell and it looks dead simple as just placing the UIButton on top of the cell.

EDIT: So I did add a new class for the petListCell and assigned it on identity inspector. I place it on the Card Design View, where the button should belong to, and it is now giving me following compiler error: "/Users/.../Main.storyboard: The feedingHistoryButton outlet from the YourWoofsViewController to the UIButton is invalid. Outlets cannot be connected to repeating content."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need do like this.

1. create a subclass of UITableViewCell like `PetCell`
2. change the class of the cell in storyboard from `UITableViewCell` to `PetCell`
3. link the button to `PetCell` like you did with the ViewController

Comment: Wait... nevermind, I thought this was the solution but it wasn't... sorry :(

Comment: you need to put the outlet in the PetCell not the ViewController

Comment: Thanks, so it does recognize the buttons properly now, but it does not actually show the button on both storyboard or on the actual device. IBAction function does work properly but I just can't see the button... https://imgur.com/a/cDREP

Comment: How about changing the color of the button's title to red, maybe the title's color is same with the background view

Comment: Wow..... by setting it to "default" I would figure that it would be any color BUT clear or whatever the background color is. Classic Xcode BS ;( Thank you for your help though.

Answer (score 1):

You can change this.

create First a subclass of UITableViewCell like PetCell
And change the class of the cell in storyboard from UITableViewCell to PetCell
link the button to PetCell like you did with the ViewController

Comment: Thanks, so it does recognize the buttons properly now, but it does not actually show the button on both storyboard or on the actual device. IBAction function does work properly but I just can't see the button... imgur.com/a/cDREP